# What are safe temperatures for dogs, indoors?

Tags: dogs, temperature

The place that I live in is suffering some heat waves, with outside temperatures reaching 37 degrees Celsius. I live in a house that heats up a bit, possibly reaching temperatures higher (just moved in, don't know the temperature ranges yet) It does not have a thermostat or air conditioning.

I have found plenty of information about safe temperatures outside (eg, https://www.dogtipper.com/heat-stroke-in-dogs, with a nice infographic) but I am looking for safe temperatures indoors.

My dog is 27.5 kg, 9 years old, and is not too active around the house. I provide her with constant water and occasional ice as treats (she likes it). But, of course, general information is also useful and appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. The same temperatures that can cause heatstroke outside, can cause heatstroke inside. Am I misreading your question?

Comment: What confused me is the fact that all articles I found talk about "dangerous temperatures ouside". If the risk is the same indoors and outdoors, that totally answers the question

Comment: a lot depends on the relative humidity where you live,pets and people can handle a lot less heat if the RH is high.knowing where you live can be helpfull for the one(s) answering your question.

Comment: Outdoors there's no shade - and that contrinutes to the range of exhaustion.

Comment: @trondhansen, sao paulo, brazil. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

65 to 75 degrees (Fahrenheit, sorry, I'm from the U.S) is the general comfort zone. (most) Dogs can survive between 45 and 86 degrees F (I'll add Celsius conversions at the end) but 65 to 75 is where most dogs consider to be normal and so will be comfortable at that temperature.

However, it can vary from breed to breed (for example, a huskies will do better in the cold than a let's say, pugs do). So, it's best to research your breed so you can determine what's best. If you're worried that your dog is already overheating, there are a few methods you can use to cool her down.

(trust me, I'm from Arizona and own a husky mix.)

You can:

- cover her with a towel wet with tepid water.
- Just get her wet with tepid water, this will create an effect similar to sweating in humans, the water will evaporate and take the heat with it.
- Don't laugh, but you can put your dog in the shower and run the water. I've done this a few times and it works best using tepid water.

You can also buy special vests that you can fill with water. There are a few warnings I should mention:

- Don't use cold water. Tepid water should do best. Using cold water will cause a sudden change which can cause complications.
- If you use a fan, DO NOT point it at your dog's face.

(18-23 Celsius is comfortable. 7 to 30 is survivable, but unpleasant)